# Counting amount of products in category not working

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, category-products

Currently I am making a custom RWD theme, with the Madison Island sample data. The category 'Women' contains 51 products in total. These products are divided in several different subcategories, for example 'Tops & Blouses'.

I looked around the internet for a piece of code that will help me display the amount of product within a category, and all answers came down to this code:

```
$categoryId = '4';
$products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCount();
echo $products_count;
```

Where 4 is the category ID of the category 'Women'. The problem is, is that  this snippet echoes '3'. But I don't have 3 product, I have 51. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to admin and edit this category (id=4). Now go to `Category Products` tab and check how many products are there. I think there will be 3 products. The total you are looking for is the sum of products of all it's sub categories.

Use this code instead:

```
$categoryId = '4';
echo $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->getSize();    

//Using count(). But getSize() is much faster
//echo $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->count();
```

Comment: This category itself contains 3 products indeed, and 4 sub categories. These subcategories do contain products. I need the sum of all the products that are in the subcategories of the category 'women'.

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Use below code

```
/** 
 * If you are in any category page then load its parent category
 * Else load root category; e.g root category has ID = 3  
 *
 **/
if (is_object(Mage::registry('current_category'))) {
    $parentCategory =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::registry('current_category')->getId())->getParentCategory();
} else {    
    $rootCategoryId = 3;
    $parentCategory =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($rootCategoryId);
}

<!--more-->

//$_categories = $parentCategory->getChildren(); 

$_categories = $parentCategory->getChildrenCategories();
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

//$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
//$layer->prepareProductCollection($productCollection);

$productCollection->addCountToCategories($_categories);

// Displaying active categories with their product count
foreach ($_categories as $_category): 
    if($_category->getIsActive()): 
?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>">
            <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>
        </a> 
        <?php echo '('.$_category->getProductCount().')'; ?>
        <br />
<?php        
    endif; 
endforeach; 
?>
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: worked like a charm! Only thing is, that I have made a little function of it. I will also put that in as an answer, but without this I could not have done it!

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code for countiong prouduct

```
$categoryId = '4';
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
echo $colletion->getSize();
```

`getSize()` gives you actually size of collection.

Comment: did not work for some reason

Comment: same problem ? have you got 3 instead of 51?

Comment: No, it resulted in probably an error. The rest of the page wouldn't load

Answer (score 0):

From the previous accepted answer, I have created this function, which will return the amount of products in the category containing subcategories:

```
function get_cat_count($int){
    $rootCategoryId = $int;
    $parentCategory =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($rootCategoryId);
    $_categories = $parentCategory->getChildrenCategories();
    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $productCollection->addCountToCategories($_categories);

    // counting amount of products;
    $cat_count = 0;
    foreach ($_categories as $_category): 
        if($_category->getIsActive()): 
            $cat_count += $_category->getProductCount();
        endif; 
    endforeach; 

    echo $cat_count; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple and it worked well for me
its just one line of code

```
<?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getProductCount();?>
```

It will display the count of the products of current category